# Restrict addition of properties to object using Flow types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How can I prevent an object type from having additions beyond the defined keys?

```
type Sample = {
  someNumber: number,
};
```

This makes me assume that the `Sample` type can only accept a someNumber key/value pairing, but if I were to add another property to the `sample` object, there is no error.

```
var sample: Sample = {
  someNumber: 123,
  someString: '123'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use exact object types

```
type Sample = {|
  someNumber: number,
|};
```

https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types